# How to get dynamically loaded data crawled by search engines?

Tags: javascript, json, web-crawler

I am facing a issue where on website, we have navigation tabs on header, on hovering drop down appears and data is populated and shown to user. This data is dynamically generated and hence it wont appear on Page source.
When researched, google crawlers crawls whatever present in page source. Though they wont crawl script tags.

Now my data is JSON data which is inside script tag and it appears on page source. This JSON data is used to populate results on navigation tabs using javascript.

I want this data to be crawled by search engines.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I happened to find [this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started). It might help you

Answer (score 0):

If is not present in DOM, then is not searchable, they wont crawl on it. It need to be in DOM so they will find it.

Comment: If they are present in DOM, still how crawler will crawl it? since it is not appearing on page source.

Comment: How do you know is not being crawled  ?  Paste the code better !

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, i couldnt find anything useful to get my query solved

Comment: I think the crawler boot loads the page just like a  normal user does when surfing the website. I never read before that crawlers read scripts, they read only content and link tags; so probably you are doing not  good  letting your content loading to the script.